# Negative regex not working in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

New to R, I want to remove from a Dataframe column all the non-words except for spaces. The following is not working properly:

```
df$text = gsub(pattern="[^\\w\\s]", "", df$text)
```

According to [here](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php) the syntax seems ok, but it produces a strange result, keeping only w and s characters.

Comment: Use `df$text = gsub(pattern="[^\\w\\s]", "", df$text, perl=TRUE)`. Or `gsub(pattern="[^[:alnum:]_[:space:]]", "", df$text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect, thank you. I've missed that parameter

Comment: Actually, `[^\w\s]` is a PCRE regex (hence you need to specify `perl=TRUE`), in TRE, it will match ``\``, `w` and `s`.